# How to use SSR pages when online, and fallback to cached index.html when offline

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-universal, angular-pwa

I'm using Angular PWA and Angular Universal at the same time, and I'm playing with the offline navigation.

The behavior I'm trying to implement for navigation requests is:

- When online, serve the server-side rendered pages for maximum first paint speed (then the client side takes over)
- When offline, fallback to the cached `index.html` in order to use the cached client app

The problem is that `ngsw-worker.js` and its configuration file `ngsw-config.json` doesn't provide a high enough granularity level to achieve that.

Here is my current `ngsw-config.json`, it provides a behavior close to the one I seek to achieve, but when I refresh the app in offline mode, it works only when the page has been refreshed (thus cached) in online mode before.

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "urls": [
        "/backend/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "serverSideRenderedPages",
      "urls": [
        "/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "strategy": "freshness"
      }
    }
  ],
  "navigationUrls": [
    "!/**"
  ]
}
```

I think that the service worker should be "Universal aware", but is there any clean solution or workaround for this while it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

As the framework does not provide this feature, I submitted it as a feature request, and a team member told me (in a nutshell) that the fact the client is online doesn't guarantee that SSR pages will render faster than loading the client app from the cache, and that in can break the update mechanism since the SSR pages refer to the latest client app.

See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30861) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use service worker to serve offline page for user when there is no internet connection

```
const cacheName = 'cache-v1';
const offlineUrl = 'offline-page.html';

// Cache our known resources during install
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName)
    .then(cache => cache.addAll([
      './index.html',
      offlineUrl
    ]))
  );
});

// Cache any new resources as they are fetched
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {
            if(!response || response.status !== 200) {
              return response;
            }

            var responseToCache = response.clone();
            caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(function(cache) {
              cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
            });

            return response;
          }
        ).catch(error => {
          // Check if the user is offline first and is trying to navigate to a web page. If user navigate to another page the website will serve them the offline page
          if (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) {
          // Return the offline page
          return caches.match(offlineUrl);
        }
        });
      })
    );
});
```

Then put this script in your index.html

```
  <script>
  // Register the service worker
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
    });
  }
  </script>
```